# Google Sheets add-on sidebar buttons are not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm building an add-on for Sheets and trying to build a sidebar with buttons to execute functions. But when I click a button, nothing happens. Here is my code:

**Sidebar.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      button {
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Generate template "onclick="google.script.run.importTemplateFromURL();">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Main.gs**

```
function importTemplateFromURL() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const response = ui.alert('This will delete all pages and data. Proceed?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
    const template = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url");
    const destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const copiedSheets = destination.getSheets();
    const sheets = template.getSheets();

    // Copy each sheet from the template to the destination spreadsheet
    copiedSheets[0].setName(" ") // Change name of the first sheet to prevent any issues if there are other files with the same name
    const newSheet = sheets[0].copyTo(destination);
    newSheet.setName(sheets[0].getSheetName());

    destination.deleteSheet(copiedSheets[0]); //Delete the page user had at the start
  }
}
```

---

The execution log looks like this when I click the button:
[image]

I published this add-on internally on Google Workspace Marketplace and tried it with different account and browsers. I also tried test functions that only sends a message to execution log, result is always the same. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Does `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url");` has a Google Sheets URL, or it actually has `"url"`? Add the function declarations of `deleteSheets();`and `createDropdowns();`

Comment: Yes, It's a Drive link shared internally in my company. The function I wrote works when I add items to add-on menu but it doesn't work when I try to execute in the sidebar.

Comment: As was mentioned in my previous comment, the code in the question is incomplete as it calls several functions that aren't included. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for my lack of information. But the result is the same with or without those functions. I tried to write a test function that only included `Logger.log("Button is working")` and the result was also still the same.

Comment: Still, you should [edit] the question. It should contain all the relevant details and doesn't include unnecessary stuff. If functions mentioned in my previous comment aren't required to reproduce the problem, remove them from the question. Also you should mention how is the sidebar is being used, name and version of the web browser, if the user is signed in in multiple account on a single account, if the user has access to Spreashseet that is called from the code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't include details about how the sidebar is used. If the sidebar users have signed in to multiple accounts, you should

1. sign out of all accounts and sign in again using only one account.
2. use a different web browser or web browser profile signing in using only one account.
3. use the web browser in private / incognito mode, signing in using only one account.

The above is because it's known issue of Google Apps Script client-side code (web applications) having problems with Google accounts multiple sign in.

---

`.withFailureHandler()` should have a *callback*. A *callback*, in this case is a function that will be executed in case `importTemplateFromURL()` returns an error.

If you don't want to add a *callback* replace:

```
google.script.run.withFailureHandler().importTemplateFromURL();
```

by

```
google.script.run.importTemplateFromURL();
```

P.S. : Remove `SpreadsheetApp.flush();`. It's not required to add this statement to the end of a function that is called from client-side code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed the code accordingly but still having the same result.

Comment: @tigressofcsejte I added info about a known issue and a workaround with several variants.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick test button

google apps script:

```
function test() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Test works")
}

function launchthetest() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("ah2"));
}
```

html: my file name was "ah2.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   <input type="button" value="Test" onClick= "google.script.run.test()"/>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

If you're not planning on getting any data returned then you don't need a withSuccessHandler

You also don't have to have an intermediate javascript function unless you need to collect data from other elements.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried it with test functions and deleted the parts you mentioned, but still having the same result.

Comment: Well I have tested this and it works.  The html was place in a script editor html file named ah2 and the other two functions were place in code.gs and then save the files.  Then you run launchthetest and a dialog appears with only a single button and when you push the button in calls the server side function test and another alert dialog appears.